# AJAX - Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter

i getting this error, and i don't know whats the reason to this.

Is it because of so many **FOR LOOP** i'm using?

```
$("#frmNew").on("submit",function()
{
    branch = $("#sel-branch");
    comp = $("#sel-comp");
    custCode = new Array(); for (i = 0; i < $(".custCode").length; i++){ custCode.push( $(".custCode").val() ); }
    recipient = new Array(); for (i = 0; i < $(".recipient").length; i++){ recipient.push( $(".recipient").val() ); }
    designation = new Array(); for (i = 0; i < $(".designation").length; i++){ designation.push( $(".designation").val() ); }
    particulars = new Array(); for (i = 0; i < $(".particulars").length; i++){ particulars.push( $(".particulars").val() ); }

    faIndividual = new Array(); for (i = 0; i < $(".faIndividual").length; i++){ faIndividual.push( $(".faIndividual").val() ); }
    faSchool = new Array(); for (i = 0; i < $(".faSchool").length; i++){ faSchool.push( $(".faSchool").val() ); }

    cgAppliances = new Array(); for (i = 0; i < $(".cgAppliances").length; i++){ cgAppliances.push( $(".cgAppliances").val() ); }
    cgRepresentation = new Array(); for (i = 0; i < $(".cgRepresentation").length; i++){ cgRepresentation.push( $(".cgRepresentation").val() ); }
    cgGadgets = new Array(); for (i = 0; i < $(".cgGadgets").length; i++){ cgGadgets.push( $(".cgGadgets").val() ); }
    cgFurnFix = new Array(); for (i = 0; i < $(".cgFurnFix").length; i++){ cgFurnFix.push( $(".cgFurnFix").val() ); }
    cgAccessories = new Array(); for (i = 0; i < $(".cgAccessories").length; i++){ cgAccessories.push( $(".cgAccessories").val() ); }
    cgTranspo = new Array(); for (i = 0; i < $(".cgTranspo").length; i++){ cgTranspo.push( $(".cgTranspo").val() ); }
    cgOthers = new Array(); for (i = 0; i < $(".cgOthers").length; i++){ cgOthers.push( $(".cgOthers").val() ); }

    ciIndividual = new Array(); for (i = 0; i < $(".ciIndividual").length; i++){ ciIndividual.push( $(".ciIndividual").val() ); }
    ciSchool = new Array(); for (i = 0; i < $(".ciSchool").length; i++){ ciSchool.push( $(".ciSchool").val() ); }

    graceSOP = new Array(); for (i = 0; i < $(".graceSOP").length; i++){ graceSOP.push( $(".graceSOP").val() ); }

    preparedBy = $(".preparedBy").val();
    agent = $(".sel-agent").val();
    noted = $(".sel-noted").val();
    approved = $(".sel-approved").val();

    $.post( base_url + "TDF/newTransaction",
    {
        branch:branch,
        comp:comp,
        custCode:custCode,
        recipient:recipient,
        designation:designation,
        particulars:particulars,
        faIndividual:faIndividual,
        faSchool:faSchool,
        cgAppliances:cgAppliances,
        cgRepresentation:cgRepresentation,
        cgGadgets:cgGadgets,
        cgFurnFix:cgFurnFix,
        cgAccessories:cgAccessories,
        cgTranspo:cgTranspo,
        cgOthers:cgOthers,
        ciIndividual:ciIndividual,
        ciSchool:ciSchool,
        graceSOP:graceSOP,
        preparedBy:preparedBy,
        agent:agent,
        noted:noted,
        approved:approved
    },function(data)
    {
        alert( "success" );
    })

    return false;
});
```

this is the first time I encountered this error. Please let me know how to get rid of this, thanks.

Comment: Usually, it happens when a recursive function call never ends.

Comment: Post error stack trace.

Comment: i already figured it out,  branch = $("#sel-branch").VAL();
    comp = $("#sel-comp").val();

Comment: It will be helpful for others if you add the stack trace here and post your own answer describing how this code change has fixed your problem.